# Should I add salt when boiling vegetable? Why?

Tags: vegetables, salt, boiling

I am a new learner on cooking and I would like to boil some vegetable: soybean, baby corn, okra, etc. I saw a lot of people add salt when boiling them but I am not sure I should do that or not, and what is the purpose of adding salt when boiling? Hope to get feedback for you guys. Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2001/nov/17/weekend.hestonblumenthal

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have heard of *osmosis*. Putting salt into the water when boiling vegetables (which are also slightly salty) will prevent water from entering the vegetables, hence decreasing the overall flavor of the vegetables.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of adding salt when boiling is to add flavor to it. Also, Salt retains the moisture of the vegetables from the inside.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to cook cabbage with just enough water not to boiling dry; keep a gentle steaming 4 mins and without salt.
So with steaming I would season afterwards.
Tom